# c# get md5 hash of an embedded resource before extracting it

Tags: c#, hash, md5, embedded-resource

We have an embedded resource and need to get the md5 hash of the file before extracting it in order to know if it is different from an already existing file, (becouse if we have to extract it to compare them it would be better to replace the file directly)

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What sort of embedded resource is it? If it's one you get hold of using `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()`, then the simplest approach is:

```
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(...))
{
    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
    }
}
```

If that doesn't help, please give more information as to how you normall access/extract your resource.

Comment: only one side note...use stream.position=0 if you want to reuse the sream... thanks for the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use MemoryStream

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.MyZipFile))
{
  using (System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create())
  {
     byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(ms);
     string str = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
     // result for example: WgWKWcyl2YwlF/C8yLU9XQ==
  }
}
```