# c++ get md5 hash of an embedded resource

Tags: c++, hash, md5, embedded-resource

I have an embedded resource bitmap with resource compiler and need to get the md5 hash of the file when the program starts.

I found a C# equivalent with the link below, but cannot find any related C++ resources so far..

[c# get md5 hash of an embedded resource before extracting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591778/c-sharp-get-md5-hash-of-an-embedded-resource-before-extracting-it)

Comment: There are lots of c++ MD5 examples. I assume you have an `HBITMAP` handle, and you want to convert that to binary DIB data, get MD5 hash. Or you want to get hash from the file. You should clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks Barmak, since this is new for me I am not familiar with the terminologies so I guess it will be converting the binary DIB data and get the MD5 hash, but first how do I extract it?

Comment: I think I may have found a solution, but need to test it first. Any other suggestions would be welcome. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for C++, you can use various libraries available like OpenSSL. This code should take the filename as input, read the file in binary mode, and update the MD5 context with the file's contents using MD5_Update. After reading the entire file, it finalizes the hash computation with MD5_Final. Finally, it converts the binary hash to a hexadecimal string representation.

```
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <fstream>

std::string calculateMD5(const std::string& filename) {
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ifstream::binary);
    if (!file) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << filename << std::endl;
        return "";
    }

    MD5_CTX md5Context;
    MD5_Init(&md5Context);

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    while (file.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer))) {
        MD5_Update(&md5Context, buffer, file.gcount());
    }

    MD5_Final(buffer, &md5Context);

    std::ostringstream result;
    result << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
    for (int i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
        result << std::setw(2) << (static_cast<unsigned int>(buffer[i]) & 0xFF);
    }

    return result.str();
}
```

Comment: there might be a few other libaries you have to include like the string and stream libraries. i didn't test this code.